# Checking if elements exist in list using python

Tags: python

I am new to python and was wondering if someone could help me out with this.  I am trying to see if the elements in b are in a.  This is my attempt.  Currently I am not getting any output.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
a = [1]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for each in b:
    if each not in a == True:
        print(each + "is not in a")
```

Comment: You should do `if each not in a: print(each + "is not in a")`

Comment: Apart from the correct answer given by Martijn you will also need to change the `print`: you cannot add a number and a string. Either convert the number to a string or use string formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing two different things, and the outcome is False; Python is [chaining the operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in), effectively testing if `(each is in a) and (a == True)`:

```
>>> 'a' in ['a'] == True
False
>>> ('a' in ['a']) and (['a'] == True)
False
>>> ('a' in ['a']) == True
True
```

You never need to test for `True` on an if statement anyway:

```
if each not in a:
```

is enough.

Comment: I'd add that, if you actually want to see if something is `True`(the object `True`, not the truth value), then you have to use the `is` operator.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Let's not muddle the waters here just yet. One step at a time!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If Python parses `if each in a == True` as `if each in (a == True)`, then why isn't a `TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable` raised? Just curious...

Comment: @unutbu -- Yeah, It doesn't parse that way.  Operator chaining is actually (probably) being used here ... (although I'm a little perplexed as to how)

Comment: It is testing `each in a and a == True`

Comment: @Duncan: Great catch, as always. It's easy to forget that `in` is a comparison operator too.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I've never understood why `in` chains with other comparison operators.  Are there any good use cases?  The cases I see in Stack Overflow are always bugs.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just say:

```
if each not in a:
   print ("%d is not in a" % each)
```

Your actual expression is using operator chaining:

```
if a > b > c:
```

parses as:

```
if (a > b) and (b > c):
```

in python.  which means your expression is actually being parsed as:

```
if (each not in a) and (a == True):
```

but `a == True` will always return `False`, so that `if` block will never execute.

Comment: Would this work in python 3.x, given that `each` is of type `int`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- I don't see how that would matter.  Each is an int, and you look to see if it is in the list `a`...

Comment: I was referring to the `print(e + " is not in the list")`. I was asking if the concatenation would work between a `str` and an `int`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- Oh, that doesn't work on py2k or py3k.  I was just copying OP's code assuming that part would work.  I updated accordingly.

Comment: Fair enough, @mgilson. I haven't worked with python 3.x so I was a little too excited when I saw a 2.x syntax error in a 3.0 post (thinking, wrongly, that it might work)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget -- If anything, py3k is **more** strict than py2k.  For example, `1 > "a"` is legitimate in py2k, but a `TypeError` in py3k.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
c = [7,8,9]

print set(a) <= set(b) #all elements of a are in b
print set(c) <= set(b) #all elements of c are in b
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to see the difference between B and A

```
 set(b).difference(set(a))
```

Comment: Or `set(b).difference(a)`.  No need to cast the argument to set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ==True.  Just:
   if each not in a:

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy using [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
a = [1]
b = [1, 2]

only_in_b = set(b) - set(a)
# set([2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
for bb in b:
    try:
        a.index(bb)
    except:
        print 'value is not in the list: ' + str(bb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that if the two lists are large. This is not the best way to do it. Your algorithm is O(n^2). The best way is to traverse a, adding the elements as keys to a dictionary. Afterwards, traverse the second list, checking if the elements are already in the dictionary, this instead is an O(n) algorithm.